# Block until the current time is 60 seconds before a given time, using LocalTime in Java 8?

Tags: date, time, java-8, blocking

I would like some advise on the best way to approach a problem I have.

I want my program to block until the current time is 60 seconds before a given time, using LocalTime in Java 8?

So it would be something like:

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.of(13, 11)
LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now()
```

Then some code that implemented some logic like: Thread.sleep(until currentTime < time1 - 60 seconds)

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `LocalTime` `minusSeconds` method to get the time adjusted by 60 seconds (or use `minusMinutes`). Then use `Duration.between` to get the duration between the two times:

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.of(13, 11);

LocalTime untilTime = time1.minusSeconds(60);

LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();

Duration duration = Duration.between(currentTime, untilTime);

// TODO possibly check duration.isNegative()

Thread.sleep(duration.toMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, converting a `LocalTime` to a `LocalTime` with 60 seconds difference is trivial. But while it is tempting to calculate a difference to `LocalTime.now()` to get a time to wait, there is the problem that time elapses while you’re calculating the difference, so the value is already inaccurate when you invoke the wait function.

While there is an imprecision in general when you’re waiting in a multi-tasking system, i.e. there will be an arbitrary execution speed and thread scheduling *after* the wait, you should avoid raising it additionally.

The better solution is to calculate a deadline, even if it might look slightly more complicated, and wait for reaching the deadline:

```
LocalTime target = LocalTime.of(12, 50).minusSeconds(60);
long deadLine = target.atDate(LocalDate.now()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                      .toInstant().toEpochMilli();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < deadLine) {
    // in case you want to support interruption:
    if(Thread.interrupted())
        throw new InterruptedException();
    LockSupport.parkUntil(target, deadLine);
}
```

This code allows you to decide whether to support interruption or not. Note that even if you don’t support it, the loop still will be needed to handle so-called *spurious wakeups* correctly. But while there will be elapsed time between the loop’s condition check and the [`parkUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#parkUntil-java.lang.Object-long-) invocation, it will be handled due to the nature of a deadline, i.e. `parkUntil` will return immediately if the deadline has been reached in-between.

The first parameter is optional, i.e. you could also invoke [`parkUntil(deadLine)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#parkUntil-long-) instead. It provides debugging hints about why the thread is waiting, e.g. when the argument has been specified, a thread dump would look like this:

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002b20800 nid=0x2aa8 waiting on condition [0x0000000002a2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000076b007220> (a java.time.LocalTime)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkUntil(LockSupport.java:256)
    …
```

showing what’s going on. Also, if the wait lasts long enough, another thread could invoke [`getBlocker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#getBlocker-java.lang.Thread-) and inspect the returned object.